# PHP preg_match confusion

Tags: php, regex

I have a string like:

```
$string = '"lorem ipsum","dolor, sit","amet"';
```

I am trying to use EXPLODE and preg_match in order to get each of the elements within " .. " as a string on its own, rendering the original string into an array.

Which would give me in the end;

```
$array[0] = 'lorem ipsum';
$array[1] = 'dolor, sit';
$array[2] = 'amet';
```

Some strings-to-be contain comma inbetween so my attempts of trying explode to separate them and then replacing or preg_matching to extract in between " .. " fails.

How can I achieve the desired goal?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should replace your combination of functions with a function that is made specifically for this: [`str_getcsv`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.str-getcsv.php):

```
$array = str_getcsv($string, ',', '"');
```

(options added for clarity)

Comment: Hello! This solved the issue like magic! How is this even possible? Genius! Thank you! ;-)

Comment: @Phil php has got loads of useful functions built in :-)

Answer (score 1):

This code should iteratively parse your string into its components:

```
$array = array();
while (preg_match('/^"([^"]*)"(?:,(.*)|$)/', $string, $match)) {
    $array[] = $match[1];
    $string = @$match[2];
}
```

Comment: I am not sure if the regex works here as it doesn't yield any results in my case? Thank you.

Comment: I have modified the code a bit, since my original version left the quotes in the last element. I've tested it with your sample input, and it works:

    Array
    (
        [0] => lorem ipsum
        [1] => dolor, sit
        [2] => amet
    )

Answer (score 0):

What you are looking for is `preg_split`:

```
$string = preg_split("/,[^\s+]/", '"lorem ipsum","dolor, sit","amet"');
print_r($string);
```

>

```
Array
(
    [0] => "lorem ipsum"
    [1] => dolor, sit"
    [2] => amet"
)
```

Comment: Thank you for your kind answer. However, I believe these is an issue. It should put -> (0) lorem ipsum (1) dolor, sit (2) amet